# Rebase from master on to feature branch fails with " Unstaged changes exist in workdir"

Tags: git

Fairly new to git.  My team has made a fair number of changes on the `master` branch (it's a SQL Database project) and I want to propagate those changes to another branch via VSTS git, which we'll call `FeatureBranch`, ready for the remerge back on to `master` when I've made whatever other changes I need to make.

When I attempt to rebase `master` onto `FeatureBranch`, I receive the error `"Unstaged changes exist in workdir"`.  I don't understand where this work directory is located.

I have run `git status` for both branches, which both return messages that they are up to date with `origin`, have nothing to commit and the working tree is clean.  I have synched all pull/push requests.

I have tried `git checkout master` and then `git rebase FeatureBranch`, however the differences being shown on `master` do not match what I have on my local repository.

I would be grateful for further guidance as to where to continue my problem solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made some changes that you didn't add and commit. 
You can fix it by severals ways, here is one:

```
git add . && git stash
```

--> you stage your changes and stash it

Next do your rebase and..

```
git stash pop
```

--> apply your stashed changes after the rebase

here's how stashing works : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing

You can also reset your branch to your last commit with

```
git reset --hard
```

but you should be aware of you can lose some works you want to keep

Comment: I've run the first command after checking out both `master` and `FeatureBranch` and they both state "No local changes to save".

Comment: Do you need to add *and* stash ?

Comment: try to only stash then

Comment: Same result :(  I am doing it the right way round though, yes? The way I'm doing it is `git checkout master` then `get rebase FeatureBranch` in order to get `master`'s changes onto `FeatureBranch`.

Comment: no you dont , you should do this : checkout on your feature branch and `git rebase master`

Comment: OK, and it then generates conflicts which I need to resolve.  I am confused as to what 'Source' is, I believe that source = `master`, is this correct?

Comment: ok so you have to fix the conflit by editing your code and `git add . && git rebase --continue` if you have nothing to add use `git rebase --skip` but i'm not sure about the 'Source' it should be master but depends on the context

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got it now, I need evaluate all the merges individually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173207/discussion-between-constantin-guidon-and-tjb).